# Network connection - batch file runs and adds my error message at end

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel, network-connection

I'm having an issue when I run a batch file. When the script successfully connects to the internet and runs, the failed message is still coming up. When I intentionally fail the script, I get a "network error 53". How do I check for this? I did not see any information on errorlevels besides:
 "if errorlevel 1 goto failed:" and then create a failed message

Script runs successfully: Error message stills come up after everything runs properly. Meaning..my "failed: " message still occurs.

Network connection fails: ":failed" part runs as it should

```
@echo off
cls
ping XXXXXXX
@echo off
net use o: \\XXXXXXXXX
if errorlevel 1 goto failed:
@echo on
ping XXXXXXXXX
killdisk.exe -XXXXXX -XXXX

:failed
echo Unable to access the network share. Please confirm your Ethernet connection and try again.
echo Please press a key to exit or the prompt will exit after 30 seconds.
PAUSE 30
echo EXITING
```

Comment: You need to exit the program after the `KILLDISK` command. Either use `EXIT` or `GOTO :EOF`.

Comment: Just one other note.  The `PAUSE` command stops execution until a key is pressed. It does not have a timeout value.  If you want a timeout then use the `TIMEOUT` command.

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate a variety of possible use cases, the Windows Command Prompt doesn't stop executing when it reaches a label (i.e. `:failed`).

In order to stop execution before the label, you can put one of the following commands before your label:

- `EXIT` - This command closes the command prompt. If you call other batch files or subroutines within your batch, this is not what you want. The `EXIT` command will close the command prompt window and stop processing everything.
- `GOTO:EOF` - The `GOTO` command generally takes a label such as your `:failed`, but in this case `:EOF` is a special reserved label that tells the command prompt to skip to the end of the current batch file. This would then return control to the batch file that called this one.

**Further reading:**

- [Exit - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)
- [Goto - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)